# How to unit test multipart/form-data file upload endpoint with RESTeasy

Tags: java, unit-testing, multipartform-data, resteasy

I have made a document upload endpoint using RESTeasy using mkyong's example at: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-resteasy/

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
public Response uploadFile(MultipartFormDataInput input) {

    List<InputPart> inputParts = MultipartHtmlUtils.getInputParts(input);

    for (InputPart inputPart : inputParts) {
        try {
            String fileName = getFileName(inputPart);
            byte[] bytes = extractFile(inputPart);
            saveFile(bytes,fileName);
        } catch (DocumentUploadException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }
    }
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

I have injected a client that will handle saving the document to make it possible to mock the injected client in tests.

```
private void saveFile(byte[] content, String filename) {
    documentUploadClient.saveDocument(content, filename, uan);
}
```

I am struggling to write tests for this as it does not seem possible to create a MultipartFormDataInput object or InputPart object.

How can I test this or refactor it to make it easier to unit test?

EDIT:

I have constructed a multipart HTTPentity but can not convert that to MultipartFormDataInput which is necessary to test the rest easy functions:

```
private HttpEntity buildMultipartData() {
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().setContentType(ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("testFile");
    builder.addBinaryBody("file", inputStream, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, "testFile" );
    return builder.build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is IMO an integration-test. If you are planning to write more HTTP tests, I recommend that you evaluate [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate).

Here is a multipart / file-upload example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/upload/upload-image.feature

Comment: I would really like to do this like a unit test. Do you know if it is possible to make an inputPart or MultipartFormDataInput in code?

Comment: maybe this code will give you some pointers (Apache HTTP Client): https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-apache/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/http/apache/ApacheHttpUtils.java#L123 - also look at line 139